# Fix Bounce Rate of google analytics

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-analytics, analytics

My website consists of many webpages having only a download option for file. Now these webpages are crawled by google and now people are visiting those webpages and downloading the files but the bounce rate is increasing as they only need to  visit one webpage.

How do i fix my bounce rate?

Will setting timer on download button help?

what do i need to do?

Additional Information: I am using LAMP

My webpage looks like this [page](http://filepursuit.com/file.php?filename=The%20Art%20of%20Deception%20pdf&id=2027615)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: this is about programming, i just wanna fire an event which will let the google analytics know that the user has not bounced @JayBlanchard

Comment: If it is about programming then you need to show your code.

Comment: ...That's how bounce works. Either remove the pages from Google with Robots.txt, or remove Google Analytics from those pages. Alternatively, use filters and segments to build a custom report without those pages included. Those are your three choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track your download as event (e.g. with an onclick event on the download button) and set the "nointeraction" flag to false (or do not set it at all since false is the default). Then people with download will have two interactions (so they are not bounces) while people who did not interact with your page will still count as bounces.

Example w/ jQuery:

```
<button id="download" name="mydocument">
 <script>
 $('#download').click(function(){
  ga('send','event','download',this.name);
 });
</script>
```

[Documentation for event tracking is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Timers do not measure interaction, so I would not use them. Rather use clicks, scroll events or anything else that indicates your user is actually doing something.

Comment: how do i track my download as an event with onclick event? i'm not sure i'm getting you

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: That would work, too (I usually try to avoid inline code, but it will give  the desired result).